# Spark fitting into Data Science Paradigm for timeseries data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, bigdata, apache-spark, forecasting

I have seen **Dataframe** as new API on Spark2 instead of **RDD**.So I have following few question about the utility of Spark in terms of time series data.

1. Is forecasting still limited to memory available in one computer
   instead of utilizing distributed fashion of Spark?
2. Has storing time series data in form of Dataframe rather than RDD
   eliminated the necessity of creating separate **TimeseriesRDD**
   which some projects did such as

   [Sparkts library](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries)

   [Flint library](https://github.com/twosigma/flint)
3. How is processing of TBs of data utilized in forecasting and
   deciding models such as ARIMA, ARMA if the first question is true?